# Locust load testing gives me ChunkedEncodingError

Tags: python, postgresql, nginx, gunicorn, locust

I'm load testing my django gunicorn nginx and postgresql application.
After about 1500 concurrent users I get the following error in my locust failed tab:

```
1   GET /   ChunkedEncodingError(ProtocolError('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(2773 bytes read, 7467 more expected)', IncompleteRead(2773 bytes read, 7467 more expected)))
```

**I have checked all my access and error logs (nginx access and error logs, gunicorn log, syslog, postgresql log), But I can't find anything related to the error above.**

Is it a Locust error? Is it a timeout error? I can't seem to find what is going wrong.

here is my locust file:

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task, between
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth


class UserBehavior(TaskSet):

    @task(4)
    def index(self):
        self.client.get("", auth=("user", "pass"))

    @task(4)
    def program(self):
        self.client.get("page1/", auth=("user", "pass"))

    @task(1)
    def artist(self):
        self.client.get("page1/sub-page/", auth=("user", "pass"))

    @task(2)
    def tickets(self):
        self.client.get("page2/", auth=("user", "pass"))


class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserBehavior
    wait_time = between(7, 30)
```

As you can see I am using Basic Auth to get through to the page. I don't know if that actually causes the error after a lot of requests.

What could be causing this error? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Someone (probably the server) seems to be closing the connection and there's not really much more locust can tell you.

There are a number of other tickets here on SO about this exception (in regards to the requests lib in general, not locust specifically), maybe one of them might help.

You can also try the new FastHttpLocust, which uses a different request library (you'll most likely still get an error, but maybe it might say something different)

It may be worth checking out your ulimits settings on the server side.

Comment: Hey @Cyberwiz, thanks for the reply! I will check FastHttpLocust and hopefully that will give me a different error.